# Show that a real solution goes to infinity as t goes to infinty

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\phi(t)$ be a real, continuous, pi-periodic function. Show that there exists a real solution goes to infinity as t goes to infinity of:

$x''-(cos^2t)x'+\phi(t)x=0$

I am having a hard time finding the solutions to this ode. I tried wolfram alpha with no luck. Am I missing a way to solve this by hand?

Thanks.

Comment: oops sorry I will edit. I had replaced it with sin(t) to try a more concrete example.

Comment: Thanks for undeleting this, and for your patience.  My answer is pretty long and, I think, thorough.  I hope to post before too long.

Comment: I finally posted an answer.  Sorry it took so long.  Hope it helps.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Set

$y = x'; \tag 1$

then the equation

$x'' - (\cos^2 t) x' + \phi(t) x = 0 \tag 2$

may be written

$y' = (\cos^2 t) y - \phi(t) x; \tag 3$

if we set

$X = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}, \tag 4$

and

$A(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\phi(t) & \cos^2 t \end{bmatrix}, \tag 5$

then we may write the system (1), (3), which is equivalent to (2), as

$X' = A(t) X. \tag 6$

We next consider a *fundamental solution matrix* of (6); this is a $2 \times 2$ matrix $\mathbf \Phi(t)$ such that

$\mathbf \Phi' = A(t) \mathbf \Phi, \; \mathbf \Phi (0) = I; \tag 7$

we note that if

$Y = (y_1, y_2)^T \in \Bbb R^2 \tag 8$

then

$\mathbf \Phi'Y  = (A(t) \mathbf \Phi) Y = A(t)(\mathbf \Phi Y),  \tag 9$

since $Y$ may be chosen freely, (9) shows that every real solution of (6) is of the form $\mathbf \Phi(t) Y$.

We next observe that the matrix $A(t)$ is $\pi$-periodic:

$A(t + \pi) = A(t); \tag{10}$

thus

$\mathbf \Phi'(t + \pi) = A(t + \pi) \mathbf \Phi(t + \pi)= A(t) \mathbf \Phi(t + \pi); \tag{11}$

we see that $\mathbf \Phi(t + \pi)$ also satisfies (7), as does $\mathbf \Phi(t)$, though with different initial data, and its initial  value is

$\mathbf \Phi(0 + \pi) = \mathbf \Phi(\pi).  \tag{12}$

Next, consider the matrix function $\mathbf \Phi(t) \mathbf \Phi(\pi)$; we have

$(\mathbf \Phi(t) \mathbf \Phi(\pi))' = \mathbf \Phi'(t) \mathbf \Phi(\pi) = (A(t) \mathbf \Phi(t)) \mathbf \Phi(\pi) = A(t) (\mathbf \Phi(t) \mathbf \Phi(\pi)), \tag{13}$

with

$\mathbf \Phi(0) \mathbf \Phi(\pi) = I \mathbf \Phi(\pi) = \mathbf \Phi(\pi); \tag{14}$

we thus see that $\mathbf \Phi(t) \mathbf \Phi(\pi)$ satisfies the same differential equation (7) as does $\mathbf \Phi(t + \pi)$, and with the same initial condition $\mathbf \Phi(\pi)$; 
 it then follows from uniqueness of solutions to (7) that

$\mathbf \Phi(t + \pi) = \mathbf \Phi(t) \mathbf \Phi(\pi) \tag{15}$

for all $t$.  It folllows from (15) that

$\mathbf \Phi(t + 2\pi) = \mathbf \Phi(t + \pi)) \mathbf \Phi(\pi) = \mathbf \Phi(t) \mathbf \Phi^2(\pi), \tag{16}$

and in general  by a simple induction on $k$ we have

$\mathbf \Phi(t + k\pi) = \mathbf \Phi(t) \mathbf \Phi^k(\pi), \tag{17}$

for positive $k \in \Bbb Z$.  We thus see that the matrix $\mathbf \Phi(\pi)$ informs us with regard to the growth rate of $\mathbf \Phi(t)$, and hence *via* (9) with regard to the growth of solutions $X(t)$ to (6).

In light of the above, we investigate properties of the matrix $\mathbf \Phi(\pi)$.   In particular, we examine its eigenstructure.  This will be facilitated by calculating $\det(\mathbf \Phi(\pi))$, which we may do with the aid of ***Liousville's formula***, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula.  Thus formula asserts that the determinant of $\mathbf \Phi(t)$ satisfies the simple first order linear differential equation

$(\det(\mathbf \Phi(t)))' = \text{Tr}(A(t)) \det(\mathbf \Phi(t)), \tag{18}$

where $\text{Tr}(A(t))$ is the trace of $A(t)$.  In the present case we have

$\text{Tr}(A(t)) = \cos^2 t, \tag{19}$

and thus

$(\det(\mathbf \Phi(t)))' = \cos^2 t \det(\mathbf \Phi(t)); \tag{20}$

the solution of (20) is easily seen to be

$\det(\mathbf \Phi(t)) = \displaystyle  \exp \left (\int_0^t \cos^2 s \; ds \right ) \det(\mathbf \Phi(0)); \tag{21}$

since

$\displaystyle \int_0^\pi \cos^2 s \; ds = \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \tag{22}$

it follows that

$\det(\mathbf \Phi(\pi)) = \exp \left (\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right ) > e > 1.  \tag{23}$

In the light of (23), we see that the product of the two eigenvalues $\mu_1, \mu_2$ if $\mathbf \Phi(\pi)$ must be greater than $e > 1$; thus at least one of $\mu_1, \mu_2$ must itself be of modulus greater than $1$; bearing this in mind, we proceed.

At this point it will prove convenient to treat the cases of real and complex $\mu_i$ separately.  Suppose then that the eigenvalues of $\mathbf \Phi(\pi)$ are real.  We can without loss of generality assume $\vert \mu_1 \vert \ge \vert \mu_2 \vert$; let $Y_1$ be an eigenvector of $\mathbf \Phi(\pi)$ corresponding to $\mu_1$:

$\mathbf \Phi(\pi) Y_1 = \mu_1 Y_1; \tag{24}$

from (9), (17) and (24) it follows that

$Y_1(t + k \pi) = \mathbf \Phi(t + k \pi) Y_1 = \mathbf \Phi(t) \mathbf \Phi^k(\pi) Y_1= \mathbf \Phi(t) \mu_1^k Y_1 = \mu_1^k \mathbf \Phi(t) Y_1, \tag{25}$

from which it follows that

$\Vert Y _1(t + k \pi) \Vert = \Vert \mu_1^k \mathbf \Phi(t) Y_1 \Vert =\vert \mu_1 \vert^k \Vert \mathbf \Phi(t) Y_1 \Vert; \tag{27}$

next, we note that

$\Vert Y_1(t) \Vert = \Vert \mathbf \Phi(t) Y_1(0) \Vert \ne 0, \; t \in [0, \pi], \tag{28}$

which follows from the uniqueness of solutions, since that forces $Y_1(t) = 0$ everywhere if it vanishes for a single value of $t$; and this being the case, the compactness of $[0, \pi]$ coupled with the continuity of $\Vert Y_1(t) \Vert$ imply that there exists a real $\delta > 0$ with

$\Vert \mathbf \Phi(t) Y_1 \Vert > \delta, \; \forall t \in [0, \pi]; \tag{29}$

in the light of (27) and (29), it is easily seen that

$\Vert \mathbf \Phi(t + k \pi) \Vert > \mu_1^k \delta \to \infty \; \text{as} \; k \to \infty, \tag{30}$

and thus is established the existence of a solution which "goes to infinity as $t$ goes to infinity."

In the event that the $\mu_i$ are complex, we must have $\mu_2 = \bar \mu_1 = \mu$, and thus $\mu \bar \mu = \mu_1 \mu_2 > e$, whence

$\vert \mu\vert = \vert \bar \mu \vert > \sqrt e > 1; \tag{31}$

furthermore, since $\mu \in \Bbb C \setminus \Bbb R$, $\mu \ne \bar \mu$; and if $Z$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\mu$, i.e., if

$\mathbf \Phi(\pi) Z = \mu Z, \tag{32}$

so that, since $\mathbf \Phi(\pi)$ is real, we also have

$\mathbf \Phi(\pi) \bar Z = \bar \mu \bar Z, \tag{33}$

we find that $Z$ and $\bar Z$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb C$, since they correspond to different eigenvalues.  Now for

$Y \in \Bbb R^2 \tag{34}$

we may write

$Y = \alpha Z + \beta \bar Z, \tag{35}$

and we have

$ \alpha Z + \beta \bar Z = Y = \bar Y = \bar \alpha \bar Z + \bar \beta Z; \tag{36}$

the linear independence of $Z$ and $\bar Z$ now allows us to conclude that

$\beta = \bar \alpha; \tag{37}$

thus real $Y$ may be written

$Y = \alpha Z + \bar \alpha \bar Z; \tag{38}$

it then follows that

$\mathbf \Phi(\pi) Y = \alpha \mathbf \Phi(\pi) Z + \bar \alpha \mathbf \Phi(t) \bar Z = \alpha \mu Z + \bar \alpha \bar \mu \bar Z; \tag{39}$

if we now set

$\mu = re^{i \theta}, \tag{40}$

we may then write (39) as

$\mathbf \Phi(\pi) Y = r(\alpha e^{i \theta} Z + \bar \alpha  e^{-i\theta} \bar Z); \tag{41}$

repeated application of $\Phi(\pi)$ to (41) is easily seen to yield the formula

$\mathbf \Phi^k(\pi) Y = r^k(\alpha e^{i k\theta} Z + \bar \alpha  e^{-ik\theta} \bar Z), \tag{42}$

which may be formally proved by a simple induction, the details of which I leave to my readers.  Combining (17) and (42), we see that

$\mathbf \Phi(t + k \pi)Y = \mathbf \Phi(t) \mathbf \Phi^k(\pi) Y = r^k\mathbf \Phi(t)(\alpha e^{i k\theta} Z + \bar \alpha  e^{-ik\theta} \bar Z); \tag{43} $

we take norms and bring out the factor of $r^k$:

$\Vert \mathbf \Phi(t + k \pi)Y \Vert = r^k \Vert \mathbf \Phi(t)(\alpha e^{i k\theta} Z + \bar \alpha  e^{-ik\theta} \bar Z) \Vert; \tag{44} $

since $Z$ and $\bar Z$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb C$, we have

$(\alpha e^{i \psi} Z + \bar \alpha  e^{-i\psi} \bar Z) \ne 0 \tag{45}$

for all $\psi \in [0, 2\pi]$; furthermore, since $\mathbf \Phi(t)$ is nonsingular,

$\mathbf \Phi(t)(\alpha e^{i k\psi} Z + \bar \alpha  e^{-i\psi} \bar Z) \ne 0 \tag{46}$

for $t \in [0, \pi]$;  thus

$\Vert \mathbf \Phi(t)(\alpha e^{i k\psi} Z + \bar \alpha  e^{-i\psi} \bar Z) \Vert \ne 0 \tag{47}$

for $(t, \psi) \in [0, \pi] \times [0, 2\pi]$, a compact set; since $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is continuous in its argument, we may infer, exactly as in the case of real eigenvalues,  that the expression on the left of (47) must attain a positive minimum somewhere on this set; thus we have

$\Vert \mathbf \Phi(t)(\alpha e^{i k\psi} Z + \bar \alpha  e^{-i\psi} \bar Z) \Vert > \delta > 0 \tag{48}$

on $[0, \pi] \times [0, 2\pi]$; it now follows from (44) that

$\Vert \mathbf \Phi(t + k \pi)Y \Vert = r^k \Vert \mathbf \Phi(t)(\alpha e^{i k\theta} Z + \bar \alpha  e^{-ik\theta} \bar Z) \Vert > r^k \delta,\tag{49}$

from which we see that the solution $\mathbf \Phi(t + k \pi)Y \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$.  Thus we have established the requested result for both real and complex eigenvalues of $\mathbf \Phi(\pi)$.

Before taking my leave of this question, I would like to point out that whereas in the case of real eigenvalues of  $\mathbf \Phi(\pi)$ we have not shown that *every* solution "goes to infinity", we have so established in the complex case; this due to the fact that the conjugate pair of eigenvalues in the complex case have the same magnitude greater than unity.  In the real case, however, there is nothing which *a priori* forces the absolute magnitudes of *both* eigenvalues to be larger than one.  Indeed, it may be that an eigenvalue has magnitude less than unity, which would give rise to a family of decaying solutions.  A deeper analysis of equation (2) may decide this question, but will not be conducted here.